# Every time I start Google Chrome, my floppy disk accesses

Tags: google-chrome, floppy

When I start google chrome (not any other application) my "A" drive/floppy access light comes on and it makes a sound like it's trying to read a disk. It's perplexing, and I'd like to figure out why it's happening.

A little more info:

Win 7 Pro SP1

Chrome Version 28.0.1500.44 beta-m

Comment: Is the default download path set to A:? Or did you last download directly to A:?

Comment: no, the default path hasn't been changed. I also cleared the download list just in case, but behavior remains.

Comment: another note: I have tried using incognito mode, and disabling all extensions, and I still get the same behavior. Something in chrome is definitely responsible.

Comment: This seems to be reported several times to Chromium: [Issue 153763](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153763), [Issue 173953](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=173953) and [Issue 234318](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234318).

Comment: @AlvinWong - thanks! looks like it's in the bleeding edge version, so I guess I'll only have to live with it a little longer. if you want to put that in as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is working on the problem and it should be fixed in the next stable release (29)
[code.google.com bug page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234318)

Answer (score -2):

Install the latest version - Google Chrome 30.0.1566.2 Dev from here - 
http://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/